# I rotate my phone - Android sensor values stay constant

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have a problem I have struggled with for weeks now.

I have an app which uses the TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor. When I'm at home it always works, but when I'm outside the sensor stops working. I still get calls to onSensorChanged, but the values stay the same, even when the device is moved or rotated.

My solution so far, is to detect if the values stay the same for an amount of time, and if they do, I unregister and reregister the SensorEventListener. Then it works again.

But why can this happen, and only outside? The problem happens both on Galaxy S3 Mini (with Android 4.1) and on Nexus 10 (with Android 4.4).

Below is the code of my RotationSensor class. The RotationSensor object is a member of a Fragment, with setRetainInstance(true);. But the error happens only with the TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor, so I guess the error has to be in the code below.

```
public class RotationSensor extends OrientationSensor { //The super class is just an abstract class which doesn't do anything
private int screen_rotation=0;
 private SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private Sensor mSensor, magSensor;
 private float[] values = null;
private Activity activity=null;
 private SensorListener listener;
 private float magField=0;

 private float[] orientationValsFlat = new float[3];
 private float[] orientationValsOpp = new float[3];
 private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[9];
 private float[] matrixI=null;

 private float[] m_NormMagFieldValues = null;


//This method is called from a Fragment's onResume method.
 @Override
 public void register(Activity activity, SensorListener otherListener,int sensorSpeed) {
     this.activity=activity;
     listener=otherListener;
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
     mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
     if (mSensor==null){ 
         mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
         matrixI= new float[9];
     }
     magSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
     mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor, sensorSpeed);
     mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magSensor, sensorSpeed);
 }

//Called from onPause in a Fragment
 @Override
 public void unregister() {
     activity=null;
     listener=null;
     mSensorManager.unregisterListener (this, mSensor);
     mSensorManager.unregisterListener (this, magSensor);
 }

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    if (activity==null) return;
    if (listener!=null) listener.onAccuracyChanged(sensor, accuracy);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (activity==null) return;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) 
    {
        values= event.values.clone();
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix, values);

        float[] remapMatrix = new float[9];
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, remapMatrix);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(remapMatrix, orientationValsOpp);
        SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationValsFlat);

        screen_rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
       float screen_adjustment = 0;


       switch(screen_rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:   screen_adjustment =          0;         break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:  screen_adjustment =   (float)Math.PI/2; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180: screen_adjustment =   (float)Math.PI;   break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270: screen_adjustment = 3*(float)Math.PI/2; break;
        }

       if (screen_rotation==Surface.ROTATION_90 || screen_rotation==Surface.ROTATION_270) arrayswap (orientationValsFlat,1,2);
        orientationValsFlat[0]+=screen_adjustment;
        orientationValsOpp[0]+=screen_adjustment;

    }
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
          if (m_NormMagFieldValues == null) m_NormMagFieldValues = new float[3];
            m_NormMagFieldValues=event.values.clone();
         magField = (float)Math.sqrt(m_NormMagFieldValues[0]*m_NormMagFieldValues[0] + m_NormMagFieldValues[1]*m_NormMagFieldValues[1] + m_NormMagFieldValues[2]*m_NormMagFieldValues[2]);
    }
    if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
        values = event.values.clone();

        if (m_NormMagFieldValues!=null && SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, matrixI, values,  m_NormMagFieldValues)){
         SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationValsFlat);
         orientationValsOpp=orientationValsFlat;
        screen_rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
           float screen_adjustment = 0;


           switch(screen_rotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:   screen_adjustment =          0;         break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:  screen_adjustment =   (float)Math.PI/(4); break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_180: screen_adjustment =   (float)Math.PI/(-2);   break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_270: screen_adjustment = 3*(float)Math.PI/4; break;
            }

           if (screen_rotation==Surface.ROTATION_90 || screen_rotation==Surface.ROTATION_270) arrayswap (orientationValsFlat,1,2);

         orientationValsFlat[0]+=screen_adjustment; orientationValsOpp[0]+=screen_adjustment;
        }
    }


    if (listener!=null) listener.onSensorChanged(this,event); 
}

@Override
public int getField(){
    return (int)magField;
}

@Override
public double getAzimuth() {
    boolean opp =(screen_rotation==Surface.ROTATION_0 && Math.toDegrees(getPitch())<-50);
    if (opp)
        return orientationValsOpp[0];
    else
        return orientationValsFlat[0];
  }

@Override
public double getPitch() {
    return orientationValsFlat[1];
}

@Override
public double getRoll() {
    return orientationValsFlat[2];
}

private void arrayswap (float[] array, int index1, int index2){
    float temp= array[index1];
    array[index1]=array[index2];
    array[index2]=temp;
}

}

 public interface SensorListener {
     public void onSensorChanged(OrientationSensor os, SensorEvent event);
     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Possibility might be:** You may not have `unregister()` the sensorEventListener before closing the application. So, the sensorManager is getting `onSensorChanged()` events in your logs.

All you need is to `unregisterListener()` before application closes. You can unregister it in `onPause()` method of activity.

*If problem still exists, then reply with the full source code you wrote and with the logcat you getting for this application.*